# VBA chart X-Axis has repeating values and does not line up with data

Tags: vba, charts, axis

I am using some VBA code to have a dynamic line graph. The X-axis is the month and the Y-axis the amounts of Pass and Fail during that month. What I have found so far is that if my data has multiple months (10 - 12 months in it) then the graph appears to be fine. However if I only have two months (see picture) the A-axis will repeat values and the graph points don't line up properly with the month that they should. Anyone experience something like this before?

Here's the code I am using

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("Summary")

With sh
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim cht1 As CHART
Set cht1 = sh.Shapes.AddChart.CHART

For q = 1 To 2
    With cht1
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(q).Name = sh.Cells(2, q + 1)
        .SeriesCollection(q).XValues = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, 1), sh.Cells(LR, 1))
        .SeriesCollection(q).Values = sh.Range(sh.Cells(3, q + 1), sh.Cells(LR, q + 1))
        .SeriesCollection(q).MarkerSize = 6
        .SeriesCollection(q).Border.ColorIndex = 11 - q
        .SeriesCollection(q).Trendlines.Add
        With .SeriesCollection(q).Trendlines(1)
            .Border.ColorIndex = 43 * (2 - q) + 3 * (q - 1)
            .Border.Weight = xlMedium
            .Border.LineStyle = xlDash
            .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = sh.Cells(1, 2)
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "DATE"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "AMOUNT"
    End With
Next

With cht1.Parent
    .Top = sh.Cells(LR + 2, 1).Top
    .Left = sh.Cells(LR + 2, 1).Left
    .Height = sh.Range(sh.Cells(LR + 2, 1), sh.Cells(LR + 20, 1)).Height
    .Width = sh.Range(sh.Cells(LR + 2, 1), sh.Cells(LR + 2, 8)).Width
    H = .Height
    W = .Width
End With
```

[image]

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: Couple things I'd look in to: what's the number format on the X-Axis, and also are you displaying Minor Tick Marks on the X-Axis?

Comment: Also, consider using a Line chart rather than a Scatterplot. That might have something to do with it actually.

Comment: Also, I just run your code and it does not produce that chart: https://imgur.com/ZuUCXhW